The probability of first passage within finite time
Let $\left(X_t\right)_{t\ge0}$ be a L'evy process with $X_0=0$ which drifts to $-\infty$. Let $T>0$. For $a>0$, define $\tau_a=\inf\{t\ge0: X_t>a\}$. What kind of assumption on $X$ should be added to ensure that
$$
P(\tau_a<T)>0
$$
for all $T$? Is the regularity of $0$ for $(0,\infty)$ sufficient?
Any help, references or comments would be very much appreciated. Thank you.
